# Que signifie « compter que par référence au renoncement » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Dans ce passage :

> Je suis devenu un être qui ne compte que par référence au renoncement,
>   un être qui refuse de se définir par extériorité .

Que signifie « compter que par référence au renoncement » ?

Comment: *J'ai devenu un être* n'est pas français, j'imagine qu'il faut lire *je suis devenu un être*.

Comment: J'ai corrigé l'erreur. Merci

Answer (score 1):

*Je ne compte que par référence au renoncement* n'est pas une phrase très courante mais elle doit signifier, dans un registre probablement religieux :

> Je n'ai pas d'autre qualité/valeur que celle qui est liée à mon attitude de renoncement, d'abandon.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like "would be" elegant/profound language, originating in  a lack of mastery regarding  vocabulary and syntax.

Where does this sentence come from?

Substituting the noun " les philosophes" for the pronoun " je" , it is reminiscent of :

> Le mépris des richesses était dans les philosophes un désir caché de venger leur mérite de l'injustice de la fortune par le mépris des mêmes biens dont elle les privait ; c'était un secret pour se garantir de l'avilissement de la pauvreté ; c'était un chemin détourné pour aller à la considération qu'ils ne pouvaient avoir par les richesses.>

François de la Rochefoucauld, Réflexions, ou Sentences et maximes morales.

> The contempt of riches in philosophers was only a hidden desire to avenge their merit upon the injustice of fortune, by despising the very goods of which fortune had deprived them; it was a secret to guard themselves against the degradation of poverty, it was a back way by which to arrive at that distinction which they could not gain by riches.<